# A light/dark theme toggle react component

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have a dark theme toggle switch for my React component that works well, but I know the code could use some work. First I am checking to see what the users' preferences are for light/dark. Then I am setting in local storage what the user has chosen as a preference and then also checking for that value. I'm still learning and would like some feedback.

My requirements:

1. Needs to check the users' system preference for light/dark
2. Needs to persistently keep users light/dark preference throughout the site
3. Add class dark to the body tag in order to active all the CSS changes

````
import React, { Component } from "react";

class LightDarkToggle extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    let bodyClassList = document.body.classList;
    let themeSwitch = document.getElementById('switch-style');

      //Here we are checking the USERS' device settings for dark theme
      if(window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
        bodyClassList.add('dark');
        themeSwitch.checked = true;
      } 
      else if(window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').matches) {
        bodyClassList.remove('dark');
        themeSwitch.checked = false;
      }

      //Persisting USERS' theme preference by checking the local storage we set
      if(window.localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark') {
        bodyClassList.add('dark');
        themeSwitch.checked = true;
      } 
      else if(window.localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'light') {
        bodyClassList.remove('dark');
        themeSwitch.checked = false;
      }

  }

  handleClick() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark');

    if(document.getElementById('switch-style').checked === true){
      window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
    } 
    else if (document.getElementById('switch-style').checked === false){
      window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="toggle-mode">
        <div className="icon">
          <i className="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div className="toggle-switch">
          <label className="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" id="switch-style" onClick={this.handleClick} />
          <div className="slider round" id="lightDarkToggle"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="icon">
          <i className="fa fa-moon-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LightDarkToggle;
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

#### `handleClick` method

Intead of calling `document.getElementById` and checking for `.checked` twice, you can store it's value into a constant like this:

```
const isDarkMode = document.getElementById("switch-style").checked;
```

then just do `window.localStorage.setItem("theme", isDarkMode ? "dark" : "light");`

After these changes, the method will look like this:

```
handleClick() {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark");
    const isDarkMode = document.getElementById("switch-style").checked;
    window.localStorage.setItem("theme", isDarkMode ? "dark" : "light");
}
```

#### `componentDidMount` method

This code can be simplified

```
if (window.localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark") {
    bodyClassList.add("dark");
    themeSwitch.checked = true;
} else if (window.localStorage.getItem("theme") === "light") {
    bodyClassList.remove("dark");
    themeSwitch.checked = false;
}
```

You could make use of `toggle` method's second parameter, which is a boolean value that forces the class to be added or removed, regardless of whether or not it already existed.

So that code could be changed to

```
const mustUseDarkMode = window.localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark"; 
bodyClassList.toggle("dark", mustUseDarkMode);
themeSwitch.checked = mustUseDarkMode;
```